# Probability question about the game mastermind ("bulls and cows" or "hit and blow")

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say you only two guesses for the game and there is *strong* significance of whether you win or lose. No repeated colors.

If you had to choose between one of these two outcomes after the first guess: would you rather get (a) exactly one bull and zero cows, or (b) 4 cows.

Which option gives you a better chance of winning on the second guess?

Comment: Setup of the game, for those unfamiliar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_Cows

Answer (score 1):

In (a) you have one bull, so the three other spaces can be anything as long as they are distinct. Can you count the number of possibilities for the three other spaces?

In (b) you have four cows, so the word must be a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of your four symbols. You can manually count how many derangements exist for four symbols.

Comment: Note that the number for (b) must be less than the number of permutations of four symbols

Comment: Thank you! This helped, but I realized where my question was flawed. I did not specify how many colors and I did not specify if the one bull option already had guesses on the board (as in 1 bull 0 cows) or you just have the one bull, with blank board.